# Search for the first 500 letters and excluding html tags?

Tags: php, regex, mysql, full-text-search

How can I search for the first 500 character, not including html tag?

Below is I came up with so far, which is searching for a keyword that occurs in a text,

```
    SELECT *
    FROM root_pages

    WHERE root_pages.pg_cat_id = '2'
    AND root_pages.parent_id != root_pages.pg_id
    AND root_pages.pg_hide != '1'
    AND root_pages.pg_url != 'cms'
    AND root_pages.pg_content_1 REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$search."[[:>:]]'
    OR root_pages.pg_content_2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$search."[[:>:]]'

ORDER BY root_pages.pg_created DESC
```

How can I add more conditions into it - first 500 letters that don't include html tag?

It would be perfect if it can search the keyword on the first paragraph only - is it possible?

edit:

thanks for the help guys! this is my solution:

```
    # query to search for “whole word match” in SQL only, e.g. when I search for "rid", it should not match "arid", but it should match "a rid".
    # you can use REGEXP and the [[:<:]] and [[:>:]] word-boundary markers:
    $sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM root_pages

    WHERE root_pages.pg_cat_id = '2'
    AND root_pages.parent_id != root_pages.pg_id
    AND root_pages.pg_hide != '1'
    AND root_pages.pg_url != 'cms'
    AND root_pages.pg_content_1 REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$search."[[:>:]]'
    OR root_pages.pg_content_2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$search."[[:>:]]'

    ORDER BY root_pages.pg_created DESC
    ";

    # use the instantiated db connection object from the init.php, to process the query
    $items = $connection -> fetch_all($sql);
    $total_item = $connection -> num_rows($sql);

    if ($total_item > 0)
    {
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            # get the content
            if(empty($item['pg_content_2'])) $pg_content = strip_tags($item['pg_content_1']);
                else $pg_content = strip_tags($item['pg_content_2']);

            # get the first 500 letters only
            $pg_content = substr($pg_content, 0, 500);

            # get the matches
            if (preg_match("/\b(".$search.")\b/", $pg_content)) 
            {
                $match[] = $pg_content;
            }

        }

        $total_match = count($match);
        //echo $count;
    }

    if($total_match > 0)
    {
        echo '<result message="'.$total_match.' matches found! Please wait while redirecting." search="'.$search.'"/>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<error elementid="input" message="Sorry no results are found."/>';
    }
```

Comment: I cannot condone the solution you came up with because it seems to me to be very inefficient, however I will ask this:

Is it REQUIRED to show how many results were found on this page considering you are simply redirecting away? To make your code more efficient, consider 'break' ing out of your loop after the first result is found.

Comment: yes the page will redirect only when a result is found. then the matched content only will display on the new page. how do I "'break' ing out of your loop after the first result is found"? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For:

> How can I add more conditions into it
>
> - first 500 letters that don't include html tag?

You can't do this with MySQL only (at least for a solution that will works in 100% of the cases) - see [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for more details.

PHP [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) would help to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as simple as stripping/skipping tags — you'll find that first 500 characters are often in `<style>` or `<script>` inside `<head>`.

Also simply removing tags will break on:

```
separate<br>words
```

If you want to do it correctly, I suggest wrting XSLT stylesheet in text output mode that converts HTML to plaintext by adding whitespace around block-level elements, removing scripts, `<head>`, etc.

A simpler way, *that kills kittens*, would be to preprocess HTML using series of regexps instead of XSLT.

After you convert HTML to usable text, put that text in extra column in the database, and use it for searching. You might even put `FULLTEXT` index on it.

Comment: thanks for this idea. never used XSLT before - need to do some research on it! thanks :-)

Comment: Nobody ever remembers the kittens that die when you parse HTML with regex :(

Answer (score 0):

If a paragraph is defined with a `p` element:

```
... REGEXP '<p[^>]*>'".$search."'</p>'
```

Don't forget to escape `$search` for regexp-special characters.

Comment: thanks. what happened to this regular expression then - [[:<:]]?? can I do integrate them into this - REGEXP '<p[^>]*>[[:<:]]".$search."[[:>:]]</p>'?? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to be able to do this from MySQL, I think the best(opinion) way would to be to have a duplicate field that contains the plain-text version pg_content_1 (and pg_content_2).

This adds space and memory overhead, but it will speed up processing during the search. If you have an ORM library on your side, you could hook an event to the onSave and make sure the plain-text fields get updated automatically.

Comment: i like this idea! the only thing is I have to change lots of things in my programme if I use this solution... but anyway thanks :-)